# Radio Button Pass The Wrong Value

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a radio button form with only two values, admin and operator.

Here is the blade

```
{{--  Level --}}
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="grouped fields {{ $errors->has('level') ? 'input error' : 'success' }}">
@else
<div class="grouped fields">
@endif  

{{ Form::label('level', 'LEVEL:') }}
<div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            {{ Form::radio('level', 'admin') }}
        <label>Administrator</label>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            {{ Form::radio('level', 'operator') }}
        <label>Operator</label>
        </div>
</div>
@if ($errors->has('level'))
    <div class="ui pointing red basic label">
        {{ $errors->first('level') }}
    </div>
@endif  
</div>
```

store controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validasi = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:200',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'level' => 'required|in:admin,operator',
        ]);

        if ($validasi->fails()) {
            return redirect('dashboards/users/create')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validasi);
        }

        // hash pass
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);

        User::create($data);
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Data user berhasil disimpan');
        return redirect('dashboards/users/index');

    }
```

I'm not sure whats wrong with the blade or maybe controller. no matter what i choose, the radio button only pass the **admin** to the database

any clue?

Comment: Where in your Store controller are you storing the values? It looks like you're missing setting the attributes on the model instance?

Comment: @SheldonScott do you mean `protected $fillable =` on the User Model?

Comment: I was thinking more like $data = new User; $data->level = $request->level; $data->save();

Comment: so i have i create request list one by one? let see if it works

Comment: Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserts

Comment: dump $data in the controller so that you can see if the issue is with the form or the controller